# Possible issues dumping a legacy MySQL 5.0 database to a local MariaDB 10.2 for develpment?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump

I've inherited a site that uses MySQL 5.0 and want to get a development version up and running with the existing data on my local (OS X) machine where I have MariaDB 10.2 but the [compatibility tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-client-software/mariadb-releases/compatibility-differences/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) are a bit hard to fathom, and don't include MySQL 5.0.

All I need is a copy of the MySQL data on the sever running locally so I can work with the "real" data, but it's unclear whether `mysqldump` will work between the two.

I don't want to install MySQL on my local machine and have dev sites that use it now, so I don't want to downgrade my local MariaDB. I *could* update MySQL on the server, but I'd rather leave it for now (it's a live service).

How would you approach this?

Comment: `TYPE=` changed to `ENGINE=` changed at some point.  What else have you encountered?

Comment: Give it a try and see if it works! If you run into problems with the `mysqldump` that comes with MySQL 5.0, maybe you could try instead to dump it with the `mysqldump` from MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: Not started yet but I’ll give it a try. I might be back…